# Can I avoid using a very large 'switch' block to give access to 400 blocks of program code?

Tags: c#

I have written an application in C# which at present includes nearly 400 mathematical functions, each with its own integer ID. To access function code, my application currently feeds the function's ID to a huge 'switch' block which has one 'case' block per function: total, nearly 400 'case' blocks. This seems to work seamlessly and quite fast, but is there a more efficient way of matching code blocks to function identifiers?

Comment: How about a Dictionary<int, Action> for non-linear lookups?

Comment: This sounds like an maintainability nightmare!

Comment: I'm curious about the other parts that refer to functions by their id's. Why would any code want to refer to say `tanh` function as `183`?

Comment: @AliFerhat: perhaps these are more complex formulas or algorithms and not just maths. For example, formulas to calculate mortgage payments or invoice calculations? I don't think I could come up with 400 variations of math functions.

Comment: @DOK it could be, but why not give them proper names? i.e. each function can be a method, a class implementing a common interface or perhaps even an Expression. In either case f will have a name, a variable can hold (point to) f, etc. Why integer indexes?

Comment: @AliFerhat I agree with you that using ID's doesn't sound like the best choice. Hard to maintain, easier to create dups.

Answer (score 5):

Sounds like you want a `Dictionary<string, Func<double, double>>` or something similar...

```
// Better, use an *enum* of function IDs...
private static readonly Dictionary<int, Func<double, double>> Functions =
    new Dictionary<int, Func<double, double>>
{
    { 0, Math.Sqrt },
    { 100, x => x * 2 },
    ...
};
```

Note that just as this refers to Math.Sqrt, it could also refer to your own methods - you don't have to put all the logic in the collection initializer. I would probably break any function which wasn't just a single expression into a method.

You'd then *apply* it like this:

```
public void Apply(int functionId, double value)
{
    Func<double, double> function;
    if (!Functions.TryGetValue(functionId, out function))
    {
        // Throw an exception or whatever
    }
    return function(value);
}
```

Note that I've used a dictionary here to be general purpose; if the function IDs are 0...n, you could use an array instead.

As noted in the comment at the start, it would be neater to use an enum of function IDs than just integers.

Comment: Thanks, will experiment with this approach and do a time comparison with the present 'switch' set-up.

Comment: Time comparison? Who cares? This can't possibly be a bottleneck, and the performance difference will be immaterially minuscule anyway. Code isn't just for making the machine do things, it's for telling humans what you want the machine to do. You want that to be easy so they can grok it and you can maintain it.

Comment: I don't understand why you would use a pattern like this over plain-old static functions. What is the advantage here?

Comment: "Code isn't just for making the machine do things, it's for telling humans what you want the machine to do". Remarkable quote. Thanks!

Comment: @WalterStabosz: It's really just an alternative for the switch block, as requested... you can put whichever functions you want in methods and refer to them from the dictionary...

Answer (score 2):

A better solution would be to encapsulate each function in its own class and then use the [strategy pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern) to swap in the function required.

Having each function in its own class has the advantage that it is simpler to see the code for the function in one place and maintains good [separation of concerns](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns), with each class only responsible for the code to implement that function.  It will make testing those functions easier as well.

It also would mean that adding functions in the future could be more flexible, as you would have the opportunity of adding functions from external sources without having to recompile.

Another benefit of this approach could be that as the functions would all implement an interface, you could scan your assemblies for those implementations at load time and thus automatically have new functions added to the list of available functions without any extra effort.

Comment: Why is 400+ classes a better design than a 400+ case switch statement?  Simply because it uses classes?  Seems like the same amount of maintenance work to me, you just traded one problem for another.  Honestly this reeks of naive OOP "design" to me (I don't mean to offend... but I don't think the `class` keyword is a panacea either).  Personally I would pass around function objects, I don't see the advantage of creating a bunch of classes when the tools needed already exist.

Comment: each class will be easier to test, it will be less likely that changes required to one function will have knockons for other functions (say by an accidental keystroke in the file or a search and replace mistake)

Comment: I don't agree at all.  I don't think it is easier to test, I think it is a lot of boilerplate code that is not making your program any better or easier to maintain.  Opening a file with one class and a function is no easier than looking up a `case` in a switch statement.  That said, I don't think a big `switch` is a good solution either.  Function objects exist for exactly this sort of use case.  Throwing around OOP buzzwords does not a good program make.

Comment: +1 - Even though it wasn't laid out in the question, taking this approach facilitates extensibility and allows the 400 algorithms to be divided into disparate logical assemblies. Depending on how often new algorithms are added (or removed), you no longer need to change the base application to do it.

Comment: I think 400 classes is a better solution than a 400 case switch statement.  I' not claiming its the *best* solution, I think that will depend on other factors...

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know `switch` statements that contain more than a few items are already optimized by the compiler to use a lookup table internally so the performance gain by switching to e.g. a `Dictionary` should be minimal. As always though, you should measure both approaches to make a decision.

Comment: Will do, and eventually feed back time comparisons to this section.

Answer (score 0):

Further re the potential for using `Dictionary`, [this fellow](http://www.dotnetperls.com/string-switch) observes that having six or more string cases and a default case resulted in the compiler generating a `Dictionary`. So, why not just skip that conversion during compilation?

Comment: Useful link; thanks. At the parsing stage of object code I have been converting a function name reference (like "cos") to an integer ID, and then feeding that ID to the 'switch' statement. I will try skipping this conversion by directly feeding the function name to the 'case' statement.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are writing your code like this (psudocode):

```
function doMath(a,b, functionID) {

    switch (functionID) {
        case 1: 
            // addition function
            return a + b;
        break;
        case 2:
            // subtraction function
            return a - b;
        break;
    }

}
```

when you want to write it like this:

```
function add(a,b) {
    return a + b;
}

function subtract(a,b) {
    return a - b;
}
```

or am I misunderstanding your requirements?

Comment: Yes, this is the sort of 'switch' set up which I have been using. I will also experiment with your suggestion and see whether it is more economic of time.

Comment: Regarding time economics, you're developing in C#, presumably in Visual Studio. With Intellisense, you'll be able to auto-complete your function names as you type them. Big time saver. Am I right to assume that you are a beginner programmer if you're asking such a fundamental question like this?

Comment: Well, er, not a beginner but self-taught (dangerous no doubt). I use MonoDevelop in Linux (much of the functionality of Visual Studio is there, including an equivalent to Intellisense). The question may not be so 'fundamental', as time is taken by C# to triage code, whether it involve a 'switch' block or involves parsing the function's name and then the allocated code block. I will do a time test within a few days and leave results here.

Comment: :) Self taught programmers are the best kind. I just thought you may have been new to this since your question reminded me of my coding style from when I was a kid.